# Linux - run a thread non stop on a core

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time

Is there a way in Linux/RT-Linux to make a specific userspace thread run in a way that no system interrupt can stop it?

Comment: Why was this closed? Seems like a specific enough question, though there are practical reasons why this shouldn't and/or can't be done.